# Scikit Learn - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to apply `Gaussian Naive Bayes` model on a dataset to predict disease. It's running correctly when I'm predicting using training data, but when I'm trying to predict using testing data It's giving `ValueError`.

> runfile('D:/ROFI/ML/Heart Disease/prediction.py', wdir='D:/ROFI/ML/Heart Disease')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/ROFI/ML/Heart Disease/prediction.py', wdir='D:/ROFI/ML/Heart Disease')
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/ROFI/ML/Heart Disease/prediction.py", line 85, in 
>       predict(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
>
> File "D:/ROFI/ML/Heart Disease/prediction.py", line 73, in predict
>       predicted_data = model.predict(x_test)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 65, in predict
>       jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 429, in _joint_log_likelihood
>       n_ij -= 0.5 * np.sum(((X - self.theta_[i, :]) ** 2) /
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (294,14) (15,)

What's wrong here ?

```
import pandas
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB    

def load_data(feature_columns, predicted_column):

    train_data_frame = pandas.read_excel("training_data.xlsx")
    test_data_frame = pandas.read_excel("testing_data.xlsx")
    data_frame = pandas.read_excel("data_set.xlsx")

    x_train = train_data_frame[feature_columns].values
    y_train = train_data_frame[predicted_column].values

    x_test = test_data_frame[feature_columns].values
    y_test = test_data_frame[predicted_column].values

    x_train, x_test = impute(x_train, x_test)

    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test


def impute(x_train, x_test):

    fill_missing = Imputer(missing_values=-9, strategy="mean", axis=0)

    x_train = fill_missing.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_test = fill_missing.fit_transform(x_test)

    return x_train, x_test


def predict(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):

    model = GaussianNB()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())

    predicted_data = model.predict(x_test)
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted_data)
    print("Accuracy of our naive bayes model is : %.2f"%(accuracy * 100))

    return predicted_data


feature_columns = ["age", "sex", "chol", "cigs", "years", "fbs", "trestbps", "restecg", "thalach", "exang", "oldpeak", "slope", "ca", "thal", "num"]
predicted_column = ["cp"]

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_data(feature_columns, predicted_column)

predict(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

N.B: Both file has same number of columns.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @EFT I've posted full traceback. Btw, I just found out that `Imputer` is deleting one column because it's entirely composed of missing value. Is there any way to prevent this ?

Comment: no one here has the file you're using with `read_excel("training_data.xlsx")`. can you reproduce this issue with public datasets?

Comment: Deleting a column certainly seems like the sort of thing that would create the mismatch you're seeing. You could try filling the column in beforehand, or adding it back afterward. The documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html doesn't seem to give a way to keep something empty. I suppose you could at least get it to give an error when this happens by using `Imputer(..., axis=1)` on the transpose of the array you currently feed it.

Comment: @EFT I removed the column name from `feature_columns` that is entirely composed of missing value and it worked.

Comment: @MaxPower Collected the data set from [UCI Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease)

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar That's good & makes sense. Since you located that before anyone else posted about it, it might be good for you to add it as answer and accept it when you can, so that anyone coming across this error in the future can see before clicking that a solution was found, and then find out what it was without digging through the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the bug. The error is occurring because of `Imputer`. `Imputer` replaces the missing value in data set. But, if any column is entirely composed of missing value then it deletes that column. I had a column full of missing data entirely in testing data set. So, `Imputer` was deleting that and thus shape didn't match with training data and that's the reason of the error. Just removed the column name from `feature_columns` list which was full of missing value and it worked.