# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (780,12964) (19419,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle

I've been trying to make a spam classifier using sklearn naive bayes but i get the following output and error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Spamclassifier.py", line 61, in <module>
        score=clf.score(test_data,test_label)
      File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37        \lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 349, in score
        return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X),   sample_weight=sample_weight)
       File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 66, in predict
        jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
      File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37   \lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 433, in  _joint_log_likelihood
        n_ij -= 0.5 * np.sum(((X - self.theta_[i, :]) ** 2) /
     ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with   shapes (780,12964) (19419,)
```

And i am attaching the screenshot of my traning data and test data directory and one of the messages
Help me how to fix this error. Here is my code

```
    import os
    import pickle
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    import numpy as np
    label=[]

    def getd(add):
       all_words=[]
       labell=[]
       email=[os.path.join(add, i) for i in os.listdir(add)]
       for mails in email:
           with open(mails) as m :
               for line in m:
                   all_words.append(line)
                   if 'spmsg' in mails:
                        labell.append(2)
                   else :
                       labell.append(1)
       return all_words, labell

    def check(add):
       all_words=[]
       labelt=[]
       email=[os.path.join(add, i) for i in os.listdir(add)]
       for mails in email:
           with open(mails) as m :
               for i, line in enumerate(m):
                   all_words.append(line)
                   if 'spmsg' in mails:
                       labelt.append(2)
                   else :
                       labelt.append(1)
       return all_words, labelt


    add=input("Enter the address of training directory\n")
    All, label=getd(add);

    vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', analyzer='word')
    train_data=vectorizer.fit_transform(All)
    train_data=train_data.toarray()
    clf=GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(train_data,label)

    chec=input("Enter the address of test directory\n")
    test, test_label=check(chec)
    test_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', analyzer='word')
    test_data=test_vectorizer.fit_transform(test)
    test_data=test_data.toarray()
    score=clf.score(test_data,test_label)
    print("Accuracy is "+sccore+"%\n")


    outfile=open('pickled_classfier', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(clf,outfile)
    outfile.close()
```

This is screenshot of my training data directory

[image]

This is screenshot of my test data directory

[image]

This is screenshot of one of the messages

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the same shape for `X` and `Y` both.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644292/3968623).

Comment: Can you tell me please how can i do that as i am using tfidfvectorizer here and it gives the output for of csr matrix....i can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Sorry. No idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using a new `test_vectorizer` on test data. This is wrong.

When you used the:

```
train_data=vectorizer.fit_transform(All)
```

the `vectorizer` learnt about the present words in the training data and stored them as vocabulary. The `train_data` shape represents that. It would have been:

```
(n_samples, 19419)
```

where 19419 are unique vocabulary words learnt by it. These become your features for the `GaussianNB`.

Now, test data will not contain all those words and you are using a new TfidfVectorizer for test data.  So that new vectorizer (`test_vectorizer`) will find different words and hence produce different features:

```
(780, 12964)
```

Then you use the old `clf` on this test data which produces the error because it was trained on data with different features.

To solve the error, just as you used the old `clf` to calculate the score on test data, you should also use the old `vectorizer` (that was used on training data) and call:

```
test_data=vectorizer.transform(test)
```

Note that I called `transform()` and not `fit_transform()` because calling `fit()` will again forget the previous training and vocabulary which we dont want.

Comment: Thanks Vivek !! You are right. It worked with accuracy of 77.69%.

Comment: Can i contact you on facebook or any other?

Comment: And please explain what exactly happens when i use this statement test_data=vectorizer.transform(test)